# Need to make lists with the values from another list. These lists must contain only a specific type of value

Tags: python, string, list, integer, tuples

Need to make lists with the values from another list. These lists must contain only a specific type of value i.e. strings, integers lists, tuples, etc. This is the original list.

```
x = [55.5,'hello','abc',10,'5','x5',0.25,['A',2,1.5],5,2,5.3,'AEIOU',('dog','cat','chicken'),[1,2,3],1001,['a',1],'world','01/10/2015',20080633,'2.5',0.123,(1,2,'A','B'),5,'chicken',2016,3.1416]
```

I have tried to use this but to no success:

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i].is_integer() == True:
        intlist.append(x[i])
    elif x[i].isalpha() == True:
        strlist.append(x[i])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are methods, not functions. The `.is_integer()` method is one I haven't seen on any object, and `.isalpha()` is only on strings. You should be checking the type with a different function, say `isinstance()`:

```
for item in x:
    if isinstance(item, int):
        intlist.append(item)
    elif isinstance(item, str):
        strlist.append(item)
```

Notice that I also use `for item in x:` instead of using the indexes.

Comment: While using the 'for item in x:' it returned an empty list but you pointed me in the right direction with the **isinstance**. Thank you

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake. It should be `isinstance(item, ...)`, not `isinstance(x, ...)`.